# OutOfMemory Error When Recyclerview Is Under NestedScrollView

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have two recyclerviews one is horizontal and another is vertical inside a nestedscrollview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/followers_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/topics_list"
        android:layout_below="@id/followers_list"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loading"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Everything works fine when i remove the nestedscrollview. But when I add and run the app I get the following error

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 8294412 byte allocation with 294776 free bytes and 287KB until OOM
                                                                at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                                at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
                                                                at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:879)
                                                                at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:856)
                                                                at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:823)
                                                                at de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView.getBitmapFromDrawable(CircleImageView.java:367)
                                                                at de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView.initializeBitmap(CircleImageView.java:384)
                                                                at de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView.setImageDrawable(CircleImageView.java:315)
                                                                at com.bumptech.glide.request.target.ImageViewTarget.setDrawable(ImageViewTarget.java:37)
                                                                at com.bumptech.glide.request.animation.DrawableCrossFadeViewAnimation.animate(DrawableCrossFadeViewAnimation.java:49)
                                                                at com.bumptech.glide.request.animation.DrawableCrossFadeViewAnimation.animate(DrawableCrossFadeViewAnimation.java:14)
                                                                at com.bumptech.glide.request.target.ImageViewTarget.onResourceReady(ImageViewTarget.java:75)
                                                                at com.bumptech.glide.request.target.GlideDrawableImageViewTarget.onResourceReady(GlideDrawableImageViewTarget.java:66)
```

This is my Java code for both adapters

```
adapter = new TopicsAdapter(getActivity());
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
topicFeed.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
topicFeed.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
topicFeed.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
topicFeed.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter2 = new FollowersAdapter();
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager2 = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true);
followerFeed.setLayoutManager(layoutManager2);
followerFeed.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
followerFeed.setAdapter(adapter2);
followerFeed.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: try only scroll view

Comment: Doesnt work @NirmalPrajapat

Comment: When you use Recylerview inside NestedScrollView RecyclerViews dont recycle anything. Because of that you can get OutOfMemory Exception. Why do you want to use NestedScrollView btw. Add to the question what do you want to do.

Comment: I want to scroll the upper horizontal recyclerview with lower recyclerview. I mean I want it to move with recyclerview.. @VolkanSahin45

Comment: then you have to implement nested recycler view . . . . there's no specific class for nested recycler view . . but you have to implement on your own

Comment: Just my opinion. Maybe you can add horizontal scrollview as first element of other recyclerview.

Comment: Read this answer [Out of Memory Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10127787/4824088) it might be help you in right way.